# Repeat all rows in left table for each unique ID in other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a team of people who are scored on up to three metrics; sales, leads and Hours.

I have a table (tblScores) in MS Access which holds these scores but only if there is any. (e.g if someone had no sales there would be no entry for them for sales)

```
| USERID  |    Metric   |  Score  | 
----------------------------------
| 20511   |     Sales   |  12     | 
| 20511   |     Leads   |  9      | 
| 20511   |     Hours   |  8      | 
| 20694   |     Sales   |  10     | 
| 20694   |     Hours   |  7.5    |
```

I am trying to create an SQL query that will output three records (each possible metric) for each User in the above table including null values where they don't have an entry for that metric. e.g

```
| USERID  |    Metric   |  Score  | 
----------------------------------
| 20511   |     Sales   |  12     | 
| 20511   |     Leads   |  9      | 
| 20511   |     Hours   |  8      | 
| 20694   |     Sales   |  10     | 
| 20694   |     Leads   |  Null   |
| 20694   |     Hours   |  7.5    |
```

I have set up another table (tblMetrics) with just these 3 metrics

```
|    Metric   |
---------------
|     Sales   | 
|     Leads   |  
|     Hours   |
```

and tried to do a left join on the metric table against the score table

```
SELECT tblMetrics.*, TblScores.UserID, TblScores.Score
FROM tblMetrics LEFT JOIN TblScores ON tblMetrics.Metric = TblScores.Metric;
```

but it is still not giving the desired output. Does anyone know if this possible?

Comment: Can you show us your tblMetrics and TblScores, Not sure which one is here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question to hopefully make it a bit clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `CROSS JOIN` first to generate all combinations, then do the `LEFT JOIN` to find which one are missing and assign `NULL`

I check access syntaxis and the `CROSS JOIN` should be write like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.Metric, S.USERID  
FROM tblMetric M, tblScore S
```

And the `Left Join` should be

```
SELECT userMetrc.*, S.Score  
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT M.Metric, S.USERID  
       FROM tblMetric M, tblScore S
     ) userMetric
LEFT JOIN  tblScore S
  ON (     userMetric.USERID = S.USERID  
       AND userMetric.Metric = S.Metric )
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried both these solutions and am getting a syntax error in from clause? Could it be that cross joins aren't supported in Access?

Comment: I check the syntaxis for the cross join in access, try just the distinct. And you probably need `()` for the `AND` condition

Comment: Brilliant. The last query works perfectly. Thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry for the first query, my access is a little rusty ;)